# How to solve this Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.Twitter.getId()I?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I tried searching in google but could not find any useful answer,

```
if(verifier.length() > 0 || verifier !=null){

                    Twitter twitter = new Twitter();
                    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(ConsumerKey,ConsumerSecret);

                    RequestToken requestToken = (RequestToken)                        session.getAttribute("twitterRequestToken");

                    session.setAttribute("twitterVerifier",verifier);
                    System.out.println("verifier : "+verifier);
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,verifier);

                    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken.getToken(), accessToken.getTokenSecret());  
                    User user1 = twitter.showUser(twitter.getId());
                    System.out.println("user1 : "+user1.getName());
                    System.out.println("user1 : "+user1.getLocation());
                    System.out.println("user1 : "+user1.getScreenName());
                    System.out.println("user1 : "+user1.getFollowersCount());
                    // For Example: to search someone on twitter.
                    List<User> users = twitter.searchUsers("antoalphi", 1);
                    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                            System.out.println("Twitter Friends :"+users.get(i));
                        }
                            }
```

after successful authentication from twitter when i try to excute i get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.Twitter.getId().
```

I want to list the logged in user profile information using java web app.

Please help.

Comment: post the code of  Twitter.getId()?
Either you forgot some arguments on input or output or wrong name of the function.

Comment: Are you sure you well import the twitter library ?

Comment: What version of twitter4j are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that you are compiling your code with one version, and running it with another version of twitter4j.

In the version that you're running it with, class `twitter4j.Twitter` does not have a `getId()` method that returns an `int`.

Make sure that you are using the same version of twitter4j while compiling and running your application.